# Runtime error for suspend function when implementing launchIn

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

The experimental implementation of [`launchIn`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/launch-in.html) throws an error for not implementing within a `suspend` function. I've filed an [issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1857) to see if this behavior is intended.

**Error**

> Suspend function 'getFeed' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function

However, because `launchIn` is the creator of a Coroutine this error does not seem valid.

```
feedRepository.getFeed().onEach { results ->
  when (results.status) {
    LOADING -> ...
    SUCCESS -> withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
      _feedViewState._feed.value = results.data
    }
    ERROR -> ...
  }
}
.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
.launchIn(viewModelScope)
```

*Original implementation*

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
  feedRepository.getFeed().collect {  results ->
    when (results.status) {
      LOADING -> ...
      SUCCESS -> withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        _feedViewState._feed.value = results.data
      }
      ERROR -> ...
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved.

The problem was that the `getFeed` method, was implemented with the `suspend` syntax. `suspend` is not needed when returning a Flow, because Flow is run declaratively, meaning `getFeed` defines the code that will be run when called. The code will run when `launchIn` initiates it rather than being run imperatively when the method is first called by itself.

This concept is defined well in this talk, [KotlinConf 2019: Asynchronous Data Streams with Kotlin Flow by Roman Elizarov](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYcqn48SMT8)

**Before**

`suspend fun getFeed() = flow { ... }`

**After**

`fun getFeed() = flow { ... }`